# Disable script on condition

Tags: javascript

Good evening, could you help me, please? From this saved (static) page, [page two](https://smartsite.w3spaces.com/page_two.html), I’m running a [script](https://pastebin.com/hhHWqEnc) that extracts, in `“Nome”` field, the publisher from the bibliographic item (*Feltrinelli*, in the example). I would like the script to be **NOT** executed when on the previous page, [page one](https://smartsite.w3spaces.com/page_one.html), there is the expression `“Editore moderno”` (that is the publisher) under the heading `“Persone, enti e famiglie”`, that is in `“fieldset.legami_tito”`).

On *Page one* I tried to set a local variable if the expression `“Editore moderno”` is found:

```
var elencoLabel = document.querySelectorAll("span.grid-6");
    if (elencoLabel.length > 8)
    {
        localStorage.removeItem("voce");
        if (elencoLabel[8].innerText == "Editore moderno")
        {
            localStorage.setItem("voce","Editore moderno");        
        }
    }
```

On *Page two* I tried this script (replacing the last line of the [script](https://pastebin.com/hhHWqEnc)):

```
function getNome(tmp) {

    var idx = tmp.indexOf('. ((');

    if(idx > -1){
    tmp = tmp.substr(0, idx);
    }

    tmp = tmp.split('. - ');

    switch(tmp.length){
    case 3:
    tmp = tmp[1];
    break;
    case 4:
    tmp = tmp[2];
    break;
    default:
    tmp = "";
    break;
    }

    if(tmp !== ''){
        tmp = tmp.substr(tmp.indexOf(' : ') + 2);
        console.log(tmp);
        if(tmp.indexOf('.') != -1 && tmp.split('.').length == 2){
            tmp = tmp.substr(tmp.indexOf('. ') + 1, tmp.indexOf(', ') -3);
            tmp = tmp.trim();
        }
        else {
            tmp = tmp.split(",")[0];
            tmp = tmp.trim();
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
function impostaNome(tmp) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article section.grid_container form div.grid-row label span')).filter( e => e.innerText.trim() === 'Nome')[0].parentNode.querySelector('input').value = tmp;
}

var elencoLabel = document.querySelectorAll("span.grid-6");
if (elencoLabel.length < 8 )
{    
    var miaVoce = localStorage.getItem("voce");    
    if (miaVoce == "Editore moderno")
    {        
        impostaNome(getNome(document.querySelector('div.meta.tito div.evidence.isbd').innerText));
    }
}
```

But with these changes, the publisher is never extracted.

Comment: can you please little detail.Like  what is your expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From _Page two_ I have to automatically extract the publisher, that is "Editore moderno" (in this case the [script](https://pastebin.com/hhHWqEnc) works correctly), then when I come again to _Page two_ I have to extract manually other elements, like the first author ("Primo autore"), the secondary author ("Autore secondario")..., so in these last cases I would like the script not to work. The script has to work only the first time, when I have to extract the publisher ("Editore moderno").